# What classes do you use to make string templates?

Tags: java, string

What classes do you use to make string placeholders work?

```
 String template = "You have %1 tickets for %d",
 Brr object = new Brr(template, {new Integer(1), new Date()});
 object.print();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options:

- [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

  - An interpreter for `printf`-style format strings. This class provides support for layout justification and alignment, common formats for numeric, string, and date/time data, and locale-specific output.
- [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

  - `MessageFormat` provides a means to produce concatenated messages in a language-neutral way. Use this to construct messages displayed for end users.

Of the two, `MessageFormat` is by far the more powerful. Here's an example of using [`ChoiceFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html) to handle `0`, `1`, and `>1` case differently:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Date;
//...

String p = "You have {0,choice,0#none|1#one ticket|1<{0,number,integer} tickets} for {1,date,full}.";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(p, i, new Date()));
}
```

This prints:

```
You have none for Tuesday, June 1, 2010.
You have one ticket for Tuesday, June 1, 2010.
You have 2 tickets for Tuesday, June 1, 2010.
You have 3 tickets for Tuesday, June 1, 2010.
```

The documentation has many more examples.

Answer (score 5):

How about [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)?

Shorthands for it include [`String.format`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and [`System.out.format`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Answer (score 4):

`String.format` is the easiest:

```
String s = String.format("%s %s", "Hello", "World!");
```

You can call it with a variable number of parameters, like I showed above, or pass it an array of `Object` and it'll use that.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
import java.util.*;


class Brr {
    String template;
    Object[] args;
    public Brr(String template, Object... args) {
        this.template = template;
        this.args = args;
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(String.format(template, args));
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String template = "You have %d tickets for %tF";
        Brr object = new Brr(template, new Integer(1), new Date());
        object.print();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
You have 1 tickets for 2010-06-01
```

Have a look at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html if you want the full reference of conversions.

Answer (score 1):

[`MessageFormat.format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) allows me to use ordinal parameters, thus easily enabling i18n

```
private final Map<String, String> localizedMessages = new HashMap<String, String>();

private void init() {
    this.localizedMessages.put("de_DE", "{2} Suchtreffer, zeige Ergebnisse ${0} bis ${1}");
    this.localizedMessages.put("en_US", "Showing results {0} through {1} of a total {2");
}

public String getLocalizedMessage(final String locale,
        final Integer startOffset, final Integer endOffset,
        final Integer totalResults) {
    return MessageFormat.format(this.localizedMessages.get(locale),
            startOffset, endOffset, totalResults);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something a little more powerful for templating strings the Apache Velocity library is pretty useful http://velocity.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Rythm a java template engine now released with an new feature called **[String interpolation mode](http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm-1.0.0-20120630/string_interpolation)** which allows you do something like:

```
String result = Rythm.render("You have @num tickets for @date", 1, new Date());
```

The above case shows you can pass argument to template by position. Rythm also allows you to pass arguments by name:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("num", 1);
args.put("date", new Date());
String result = Rythm.render("You have @num tickets for @date", args);
```

Links:

- Check the [full featured demonstration](http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com/)
- read [a brief introduction to Rythm](http://software-lgl.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/rythm-easy-to-use-high-performance-java.html)
- download the [latest package](https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/downloads) or
- [fork it](https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm)